# Ph too low, but pitched anyway

Tags: cider

After pressing my apples for cider, I tested the PH level and it was 2.7. Although the taste was quite sweet and not too sharp. I decided against sodium metabisulphate, from what I've read, but now thinking I should have added chalk. Has anyone made cider at this acid level and did it turn out alright?

Answer (score 2):

The acidity will mellow out in time.  So high acidity means you will have to be patient, and let it age a few additional weeks or months.

This other post also has a solution for this problem, either add some dry malt extract or some calcium carbonate:  [How to stop Cider becoming too acidic](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-do-i-stop-cider-becoming-too-acidic?rq=1)