# What is too high a gravity to bottle condition cider?

Tags: cider, specific-gravity

I tasted my cider today and if I could bottle it now I would. The only problem is that the gravity is at 1.012. My concern is that I could create bottle bombs if I bottled it now. Is it possible to bottle it as is (without additional priming sugars), assuming that most of the sugars are fermentable? The last cider I did was too dry at 1.0015. I am trying to avoid the same mistake twice. Thanks!

Comment: Are your gravity numbers correct? I often bottle beer at 1.012, but I couldn't distinguish a 1.0015 from a 1.000 or 1.002 even.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct gravity. And yes, I would normally bottle also if this was a beer with unfermentable sugars. But, I know this will ferment very low if not totally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this cider made similarly as the cider you made previously, or have you changed things with the recipe and how it is made?

I wolud be very afraid that the yeast would continue working on the remianing sugars and try to bring it down to 1.0015 in the bottle.

I have not made any ciders but with beer you always want the yeast to finish of more or less all the sugar it can eat. Short of killing off the yeast and then carbonating with CO2 afterwards that is the best way of controlling carbon content.

Killing off the yeast can have other bad consequences for taste though as the yeast might not be done eating up byproducts and cleaning up the taste.

In beer you "control" sweetens with mashing temperature (producing more or less fermentable sugars) and the yeast strain used. In addition hop can have an influence over the perceived sweetens of the final brew.

Remembered one more way to control sweetens. Adding sugar the yeast can't eat. What sugar that is may depend on yeast strain. Dextrin or lactose might work.but do so long before putting it in a bottle,  and make certain you do not get an infection in the bottles. Carbonation from bacteria can also produce botlebombs.

Comment: Yes, same recipe. It will ferment out completely if I leave it be. I am just trying to understand how many points does a cider have to ferment down to create enough gas for good carbonation. My suspicion is that is probably isn't much...maybe 1 point lower? Which means that if this yeast (US-05) continues to work well under the current abv (8.5%) and under increased carbonation pressure, it could very well ferment enough additional sugars to cause the bottles to burst.

Comment: I'm not certain of the process of making cider. But with beer when you mash you get more or less fermentable shugars with  the temperature and time used for mashing. As a home brewer it can be difficult to get all parameters the same between each brew even with the same grain bill and water content. For that reason it is not so easy to say exactly what fg the brew will land at. Ultimately you will not make the cider les dry by boteling now. Here is a link that gives some advice on what you could do https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-do-i-stop-cider-becoming-too-acidic?rq=1